# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Update - With Error: "YOUR SYSTEM IS NOW UNBOOTABLE!"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, mdadm

I just did an `apt-get dist-upgrade` and saw the following error:

```
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/md1
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
W: mdadm: the array /dev/md3 with UUID 8b1840ac:12c70cae:3fb6082e:e5593158
W: mdadm: is currently active, but it is not listed in mdadm.conf. if
W: mdadm: it is needed for boot, then YOUR SYSTEM IS NOW UNBOOTABLE!
W: mdadm: please inspect the output of /usr/share/mdadm/mkconf, compare
W: mdadm: it to /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf, and make the necessary changes.
W: mdadm: the array /dev/md1 with UUID 3d78c4fe:0806edff:3fb6082e:e5593158
W: mdadm: is currently active, but it is not listed in mdadm.conf. if
W: mdadm: it is needed for boot, then YOUR SYSTEM IS NOW UNBOOTABLE!
W: mdadm: please inspect the output of /usr/share/mdadm/mkconf, compare
W: mdadm: it to /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf, and make the necessary changes.`
```

When i ran `/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf` the files differed by going from this:

```
ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 devices=/dev/sda1,/dev/sdb1
ARRAY /dev/md3 level=raid1 num-devices=2 devices=/dev/sda3,/dev/sdb3
```

to this:

```
ARRAY /dev/md3 metadata=0.90 UUID=8b1840ac:12c70cae:3fb6082e:e5593158
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=0.90 UUID=3d78c4fe:0806edff:3fb6082e:e5593158
```

I made those changes, but when I run `update-initramfs -u`, I get this error:

```
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/md1
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
```

Here's my `fstab`:

```
/dev/md1        /               ext3    defaults                1 1
/dev/sda2       none            swap    sw
/dev/sdb2       none            swap    sw
/dev/vg00/usr   /usr            xfs     defaults                0 2
/dev/vg00/var   /var            xfs     defaults,usrquota       0 2
/dev/vg00/home  /home           xfs     defaults,usrquota       0 2
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  gid=5,mode=620          0 0
none            /proc           proc    defaults                0 0
none            /tmp            tmpfs   defaults                0 0
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I do not have any encrypted disks on this machine, so I'm not sure why cryptsetup is saying anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

So I rebooted and everything went fine.

What I did was put the contents of `/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf` into `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`, then by uninstalling `cryptsetup` (its not being used), the `update-initramfs -u` command ran without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Ubuntu, so I can't give you answers, but since this seems imminent I can give you suggestions, a *one-button-press* ubuntu dist upgrade once thrashed my system too

1. Check that the mdadm service is started before dmcrypt in the initramfs dependency hierarchy.
2. Depending on what is compiled into your kernel, it can assemble md1 since it uses the 0.90 superblock format. (If you used the Linux Raid Autodetect partition format). Here is my grub (legacy) line (I don't use an initramfs)

`kernel /boot/kernel_r23 root=/dev/md125 md=125,/dev/sda3,/dev/sdb3,/dev/sdc3`

Comment: Hmmm... I'm a programmer, most of what you said is beyond me. ;)